# Subscriptions - Specified resource is not supported for MSA requests

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, subscription

I use the Graph API to synchronize calendars with an app created from an Office 365 account (with a developper license).

I do user tests with an account outlook.com and hotmail.com (I log in oauth), all API calls work, however, as soon as I try to create a subscription with the endpoint **"/subscriptions"**, the API returns this error:

> 400 - Specified resource is not supported for MSA requests

If I connect with an Office 365 user account, the API doesn't return an error.

How can my outlook, hotmail, live... users use my app with the endpoint "/subscriptions"?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Without code showing to how you're calling this, there isn't much the community can do beyond guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions' endpoint instead of 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions'.